# A question about pdfpages: can I have a heading?

Tags: sectioning, pdfpages

I'm using pdfpages to include some pdf files in a current document.  But I'd like some of these pdf pages to have a LaTeX heading, either with a sectioning command `\section*{This is how it is}` or just a bold-faced line: `\textbf{This is how it is}`.  However, pdfpaged material seems to like being on a page by itself, and even if I include a scaling factor I can't get the heading and the pdf page together.  What happens is that I get the heading on a page by itself, and the pdf page on the *next* page.

I can get the result I want if I use `includegraphics` instead of `includepdf` but then of course I only get the first page of the pdf file included.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `pagecommand` option like this:

```
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\section{Second title}\label{mylabel}\hfill}]{file.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand={\hfill}]{file.pdf}
```