# Add pdf with pdfpages under a section without getting blank space

Tags: pdfpages

I have a question that moves from [this previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199816/easiest-way-to-insert-moderncv-based-cv-into-another-latex-document).

I am following the answer over there, which means that I am compiling my CV without page numbering and then I am adding it via `pdfpages`. However, there is an additional problem, namely that the CV should be in a **section** of the final text of its own. What happens now is that the section starts at a page and then the CV starts on the next page.

Is there a way to avoid it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130197

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, which actually does the job. However, there is an overlap between the title of the section and the beginning of the imported pdf, i.e., the two lines of text are one over the other. Do you know if there is a way to fix this? Also, the section title appears on every page of the pdf with increasing numbering.

Comment: Add scale=0.90 to the \includepdf option. The included pdf page is too big to fit on your page.

Comment: @Ross Thanks a lot: that actually works for the first problem, however I still have an increasing number of sections, one for every page of the added pdf. Do you think this can be fixed? *[If you think can be useful I could add a MWO]*

Comment: You can use `\includegraphics[page=...]` instead of pdfpages.  In fact, that is how pdfpages does it.

Comment: It should be: `\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\section{Section title}}]{file.pdf}` then `\includepdf[pages=2-]{file.pdf}`. Adding a MWE is always best practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. In the end I implemented an ad hoc solution. That is, I divided the pdf file in two files, first page and all the others: for the first page I used the `\pagecommand` with section, while for the other I used emptypage. That worked fine.